# How to trigger celery signals on tests

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I'm writting a tests for celery `task_failure` signal handler, however I have a problem to trigger this signal during tests.
How can I trigger celery signal manually?

I have following code:

***tasks.py***

```
def do_something():
    print "hello"

@app.task(name='simple_task')
def simple_task(x, y):
    do_something()
    return x - y

@task_failure.connect(sender='simple_task')
def task_failure_handler(args=None, **kwargs):
    logger.exception("Task failed")


@celeryd_init.connect
def init_signals(*args, **kwargs):
    task_failure.connect(
        task_failure_handler
        sender='simple_task'
    )
```

and I'm trying to write a tests to check if signal is called when task fail.

So far I've done:

```
@patch('tasks.task_failure_handler')
@patch('tasks.do_something')
def test_signal_handler(task_mock, signal_mock):
    task_mock.side_effect = Exception()
    tasks.simple_task.apply((1, 2,))
    assert signal_mock.called
```

But signal is not triggered and assertion fail.

I did some debugging and problems seems to be related with `self._live_receivers(sender)` in `celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py`
    `self._live_receivers(sender)` is empty despite the fact that recipient is available, but none of these conditionals: `r_senderkey == NONE_ID or r_senderkey == senderkey` are true. I do not understand why is this happening.

Why my receiver is not a live? How can I trigger signal manually?

Comment: What are you actually testing there? You assert that the `signal_mock` is called but the only thing you are calling is a mock.

Comment: @KlausD.: You have right. I fixed my example.